# ionic 3 Build failed for task :processDebugManifest

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I am having trouble in building my ionic 3 app. Every time I try to build the android app it gives the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value val
ue=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:2
7:9-31
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] Androi
dManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element a
t AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

My ionic info is as follows:

cli packages: (C:\Users\SystemOne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Node : v6.10.0
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Any help would be much appriciated

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Android build is attempting to support multiple versions, take note of this part: [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**25.3.1**] - this is the older version that it is trying to support.

Put this at the end of your app module build.gradle(in your project folder):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace the `details.useVersion` with the older version number.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=26.+
```

Font: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/362#issuecomment-366457197

Answer (score 0):

It's a good advice to do

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.1
```

after every plugin installation or update.