# Ionic 3 Android Failed Build Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've checked a number of posts and Github issues but still not been able to solve this build error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-36:19 to override.
```

I've tried adding `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` and other solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411610/ionic-3-build-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest) as well as other AndroidX solutions found in these posts:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/193

[Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed)

To no avail.

I've even tried updating Android Studio to the latest version and tried the `Migrate to AndroidX` option from the refactor menu.

Lastly, I have also tried using Cordova `android@8` as well as `@7.4.1` both with variations of the above.

I would have tried adding the following to the gradle.properties file, as suggested in the Github link above, however I don't have one of these in this Ionic project:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

As the error states, I've added `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to the application tag within `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-36:19 Error:
        tools:replace specified at line:5 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
/Users/simontaylor/Development/Rehab Guru/mobile/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write this line into AndroidManifest.xml file in application tag: tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

Comment: This has been tried and it just presents another error.

Answer (score 0):

add the following one line in application tag in the AndroidManifest file

```
tools:node="replace"
```

Comment: This has been tried and it just presents another error. I've moved to capacitor as I'm completely fed up with Cordova.

Comment: I've added this to the original question.